# Как задать цвет для BORDER в CSS в вариации linear-gradient?

Tags: css

```
border-color:linear-gradient(136.96deg, #EB177E 0%, #893EF9 103.66%); НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
```

Comment: вы искали ответ в поисковике?

Comment: Никак. Используйте блок обвертку и задайте ему фоновым цветом, и добавьте падинги равные вашему размеру бордера.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение

border-right: 2px solid transparent;

```
border-image: linear-gradient(136.96deg, #EB177E 0%, #893EF9 103.66%);

border-image-slice: 1;
```